# "False Consonances of Melancholy" album title

Tags: album-title, baroque

What does the title of Gli Incogniti's "False Consonances of Melancholy" refer to?  Is it an allusion to something?  Is it word play of some sort?

Comment: There's no tag for "baroque" or "album-title" and I don't have the rep to create tags yet.  Those would be good tags for this.

Comment: Just added the tags for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the booklet states, it relates to **Nicola Mattei**'s treatise on continuo playing for the guitar, titled:

> The False Consonances of Musick (1682)

It also quotes from this work

> You must not play allwayes alike, but sometimes Lowd and sometimes softly, according to your fancy, and if you meet with any Melancholy notes, you must touch them sweet and delicately.